# Phonegap App on Android

Tags: android, cordova, resolution

I have just developed an iPhone app using Phonegap and I now tried to post it to Android using Android SDK and guide available on Phonegap website. Everything works good except screen resolution and as I tested it on Android Emulator setting Nexus One Resolution, I found everything is too small and leaves half the screen empty. Is there a setting I need to put to make it exactly float like on iPhone?

**UPDATED**

I am using this viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `meta Veiwport tag` or `CSS media queries` for multiple screen support

References :

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html
http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html
http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html#metaviewport

Comment: Check I have added some references